# Individually sum random numbers not in an array?

Tags: java, loops

This is part of a school assignment which I've already turned in, I was graded down in one portion because the total sum of the random numbers was supposed to be adding the individual numbers together, not each line.

So if the lines read:

1 2 3

4 5 6

The total should be 21, not 579 as my program is doing now. I've really been struggling trying to figure this out. I tried generating a different random number object for each integer, for a total of three of them but that completely screwed up my output.

We're learning arrays next week, and after researching online I could do this easily with an array, but the assignment was to be done without arrays. How can I sum each entry individually? Thanks for any help!

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lottery {


public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int gameType, gameTimes;
int randomNums, lotNum, sum = 0;    

System.out.println("\t\t Welcome to\n \t\tJAVA LOTTERY!\n\n\n");

System.out.print(" Would you like to play with 3, 4, or 5 numbers? ");
  gameType = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("\n\n Now think about a number with " + gameType + " digits and remember it!\n\n\n");

System.out.print(" How many games should we play? ");
  gameTimes = input.nextInt();  


System.out.println("\n\n We're all done! We played " + gameTimes + " games!\n\n" + 
        " The numbers randomly selected were: ");

for(int i = 0; i < gameTimes; i++)
  {
   lotNum = 0;

   for(int j = 0; j < gameType; j++)
   {
    randomNums = (new Random()).nextInt(10);

    lotNum = (lotNum * 10) + randomNums;

    System.out.print(" " + randomNums);    
   }//end nested for loop

   System.out.println();

   sum += lotNum;

  }//end for loop

System.out.println("\n\nThe total of all of the numbers was " + sum );  

input.close();
    }//end main method
}//end lottery class
```

Comment: I'm not sure what lotNum is for. If the task is to sum the random numbers, why do you add lotNum to the sum, and not randomNums?

Comment: @JBNizet it came from my sloppy code and rewriting it several times to get a working product, it was a workaround. The lotNum was my way of separating individual numbers, but it didn't work as intended. I was pretty confused when I wrote a lot of this, but I got it working (at least I thought I did) and was content with it as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
lotNum = (lotNum * 10) + randomNums;
```

to

```
lotNum += randomNums;
```

Comment: Thanks Raman! This worked well. I knew it was going to be something with that lotNum variable but I couldn't figure out what to do with it.